# XSLT: group elements without deleting neighboring elements

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I want to prepare the index entries in a Word file for an XSL-FO transformation.

The index entry always starts with

`w:r/w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType="begin"` and ends with
`w:r/w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType="end"`.

In between, one or more elements may contain the content.

How do I get the content as a contiguous string?

I have tried it with different variants of for-each-group. But the problem is that it always removes the other w:r that are not part of the index.

How can I do this?

**Source-XML**

```
<w:p>      
    <w:r>
        <w:t>Stahl und Beton</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>lässt</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:t> sich aus dem alten Namen des Materials ableiten.</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
    <w:r>
        <w:instrText> XE "</w:instrText>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:instrText>Moniereisen</w:instrText>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:instrText>" </w:instrText>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

**One of the XSLT attempts**

```
    <xsl:template match="w:p[w:r[w:fldChar[@w:fldCharType = 'begin']]]">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="w:r[w:fldChar[@w:fldCharType = 'begin']]">
            <xsl:if test="self::w:r[w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType = 'begin']">
                <indexentry>
                        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()[position() gt 1]"
                            group-ending-with="w:r[w:fldChar[@w:fldCharType = 'end']]">
                            <xsl:if test="position() eq 1">
                                <xsl:apply-templates
                                    select="current-group()[not(self::w:r[w:fldChar[@w:fldCharType = 'end']])]"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each-group>
                </indexentry>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
```

**Actual output (simplified)**

```
<indexentry>
    <w:r/>
    <w:r/>
    <w:r/>
</indexentry>
```

**Desired output**

```
<w:p>      
    <w:r>
        <w:t>Stahl und Beton</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>lässt</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:t> sich aus dem alten Namen des Materials ableiten.</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <indexentry> XE "Moniereisen" </indexentry>
</w:p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the outer `xsl:if` you want an `xsl:choose/xsl:when` instead where the additional `xsl:otherwise` pushes the `current-group()` with `xsl:apply-templates` to your default templates (e.g. the identity transformation). I don't know whether you need the inner `xsl:if` and the `xsl:apply-templates`, I would think that doing `<xsl:value-of select="current-group()[position() != last()]/w:r/w:instrText"/>` suffices.

Comment: The forest for the trees, Detective, the forest for the trees. Yep, that was the solution. Thx. I still changed the `apply-templates` in the second `for-each-group` to a `value-of` to get the string.